# Explain MongoDB log output

Tags: mongodb, database-performance

I have location-collection with indexing `timestamp_1, timestamp_2 and user_id` field. When executing query (you can see in following log) then query taking ~3 min (175670ms). I don't recognize why is It happening!!
I have attached following MongoDB-Log.
Can anybody explain me following log and how can I optimise it ??

> 2017-04-12T17:04:33.759+0000 I COMMAND  [conn167] query
>   location-collection query: { orderby: { timestamp_1: 1 }, $query: {
>   $and: [ { timestamp_1: { $lte: 1492016294486.0 } }, { timestamp_2: {
>   $gte: 1491993563400.0 } }, { user_id: "jkfjlsjfflki-14asddsd" } ] } }
>   planSummary: IXSCAN { user_id: 1 }, IXSCAN { user_id: 1 }
>   ntoreturn:1000 ntoskip:0 keysExamined:27254 docsExamined:27254
>   hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0
>   numYields:3350 nreturned:67 reslen:176574 locks:{ Global: {
>   acquireCount: { r: 6702 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 3351 } },
>   Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 3351 } } } **175670ms**

One more question: I am creating my own value of "_id" field so any drawback this way  ?? I am creating just string value and expecting mongoDb index it without any issues.

> 2017-04-12T17:04:41.979+0000 I COMMAND  [conn150] query db.users
>   query: { orderby: { _id: 1 }, $query: { _id:
>   "USR-dfhsddf-14905426shfkjdhf" } } planSummary: IDHACK ntoreturn:1
>   ntoskip:0 keysExamined:1 docsExamined:1 idhack:1 cursorExhausted:1
>   keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:1 reslen:1291
>   locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount:
>   { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } 2627ms

**Thanks in Advance!!**

Answer (score 8):

Answering the second question first - It is fine to use your own value for _id.  MongoDB will index it properly.  The consequence of doing this is that it is now your applications responsibility to ensure that there are no duplicates.

The default MonogDB ObjectId type also includes the timestamp in the value. This means that ordering by the _id field when it is an ObjectId will return results by insertion order (or technically timestamp when the ObjectId was created order).

As for the log output, query performance output values are from the Database Profiler.  You can see the list of values at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/.

A very useful tool for the query performance is `explain()`, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/.  You will have to test on your own systems how the queries perform.

It seems as though you have three different indexes on your collection on the individual fields: `timestamp_1`, `timestamp_2`, and `user_id`.

The query is comparing three fields:

- `timestamp_1` is less than a value
- `timestamp_2` is greater than a value
- `user_id` equals a value

You are also ordering by the `timestamp_1` field in the output.

The `planSummary: IXSCAN { user_id: 1 }, IXSCAN { user_id: 1 }` is stating that the query planner is choosing the index on `user_id` for the query, then choosing the index on `user_id` again to use for sorting, which is not the the field you actually want to sort on.  For reference, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/nQlmVdODo-M.

The `keysExamined:27254` means that the index scan examined 27254 keys in the index.  The `docsExamined:27254` means that MongoDB pulled up 27245 documents off of disk to examine the contents.  The `nreturned:67` states that the result of the query returned 67 documents.  The `user_id` index is scanned, finds 27254 matches, then each document is retrieved from the collection. Those documents are parsed and `timestamp*` fields are compared, and the 67 matching records are returned.  The `timestamp_1` and `timestamp_2` indexes are not used.

MongoDB stores indexes as B-TREEs and does allow compound indexes (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/).  You can test making new combinations of indexes, profile the results, and see which one works best for your application.  A compound index with all three fields will allow the query to analyze all of the query fields (`user_id`, `timestamp_1`, and `timestamp_2`) using only the index, which should reduce the number of documents that MongoDB needs to read off of disk.  One potential example is:

```
db.collection.createIndex({user_id:1, timestamp_1:1, timestamp_2:-1)
```

This index would allow the Mongo query planner to match the `user_id` field, then find results where `timestamp_1` is less than the value, then find any more results where `timestamp_2` is greater than its value.  Because `timestamp_1` is listed before `timestamp_2`, the matching records are already sorted, which may also allow MongoDB to skip the sort phase.  You will need to test this on your own system to verify that its performance is better.  Depending on the cardinality of the documents in the collection, you could try putting the timestamp fields ahead of the user_id field.